Add newline using ExcelJS
I would like to add a newline in a cell using ExcelJS (using the newest version 4.4).
I have tested with \r\n, \r and \n and all of them gives me the same results: The newline is visible in the formula-bar, but not directly in the cell itself.
It displays it in the cell after you manually click on the formula bar.
My question is: Can this be resolved, if yes, how?
Example
In Typescript using the newline commands:

How it is visible in Excel:

Please note that in the formula bar it is displayed correctly.
When clicking in the Formula bar and next clicking to another cell it shows this:

Any ideas how this can be resolved so the newline is immediately visible in the cell itself?

Could you apply "wrap text" formatting to the cells which will have new lines and see? When text is manually entered with a newline, it wraps automatically, but, for example,  with ="ab" & CHAR(10) & "cd" it does't until "wrap text" is set.

You are right nkavli, it does the trick. I shall comment this as an answer .

As nkavli already commented:
In the documentation in GitHub for ExcelJS you can use:
// set cell to wrap-text
ws.getCell('D1').alignment = { wrapText: true };

And voila: the result is displayed correctly.
